# Ubuntu 19.10 - Freeze when waking from suspension

Tags: suspend, power-management, amd-ryzen

I think it is a common problem, but I was hoping that someone *might* know something...

I have an ASUS 433 Zenbook, with an AMD R5-3500U APU. (I.e., no NVIDIA).

When I put the Laptop in suspend mode, it immediately wakes up and then hangs up when I try to log in. At that point, the screen goes black and the laptop becomes totally unresponsive (e.g., caps lock light does not go on and off, so I know even the keyboard is not detected at that point).

The light at the side of the Laptop (next to the battery indicator) that goes on when the Laptop is on, does *not* change colours (usually, in Laptops, this light should blink and/or go orange). So, I suspect it might not even fully go to sleep?

Anyone got any ideas?
Cheers.

EDIT:

1. Please be slow when explaining, I am new to Linux and know next to nothing:
2. I saw that "blootooth" could be an issue for this, so I disabled it and tried to suspend. It woke up again, but this time, the log-in screen was not displayed, just a flash of artefacts (a bunch of Pixels, like you get when the GPU is not working properly) and than again a blank screen. The Laptop remained responsive for some time (as it usually does. It freezes on login not before.)

So I guess Bluetooth does have some part in this error, but I guess the GPU as well...

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to learn about "Power Management", which includes Suspend/Hibernate/Wake/Resume. Read `man pm-is-supported`, and do: `for state in suspend hibernate suspend-hybrid ; do sudo pm-is-supported --$state; if [[ $? -eq 1 ]] ;then echo "$state is NOT supported" ; else echo "$state is supported"; fi; done`

Comment: @waltinator Hi, and thanks for the comment. What do you mean by "and do:[...]"? Should I type "for state in suspend hibernate suspend-hybrid ; do sudo pm-is-supported --$state; if [[ $? -eq 1 ]] ;then echo "$state is NOT supported" ; else echo "$state is supported"; fi; done" in the terminal? - I should maybe add to my post that I am very new to Linux. Thanks.

Comment: You can simply copy-and-paste the text into a terminal. It will report on the three ways to suspend/hibernate, and if your system, as currently configured, supports this mode. Of course, read `man pm-is-supported` first.

Comment: my AMD Ryzen 2500u X360 says supported for all those three functions. Out of the box none of them are, (19.10) . I have to unplug USB devices before suspend so they dont lock up. suspend sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. nice script though.

Comment: @waltinator Hi and thank you. I did do that. It says that all 3 are supported. However, the laptops still freezes up :/

Comment: it is interesting I am have the same problem w. my xps 7590. That command says that not one is supported :(